# How to use Vue3 Router in other VUE files

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

So I'm using Vue3. I'm not sure how in the individual VUE file javascript sections to use the router from other pages in the application. So if I have a Register.vue view which is /register in the application how on that .VUE can I use the router in the javascript in that script section.

***main.ts***

```
import './assets/main.css'

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'

import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import vue3GoogleLogin from 'vue3-google-login'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(createPinia())
app.use(router)

app.use(vue3GoogleLogin, {
  clientId: ''
})

app.mount('#app')
```

***OTHER.VUE***

```
<SCRIPT setup>

Axios.post(etc etc).then(etcetc){
 how do I do route change
}

</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: `useRouter()` ?

Answer (score 0):

In Composition API:

```
import {useRouter} from 'vue-router';
const router = useRouter();
```

In Options API:

```
this.$router
```

In templates:

```
$router
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve is:

- Redirect to a route based on the response of your `Axios.post`.

If so, you should use:

```js
<script setup>
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

const router = useRouter()

function redirectPage() {
  Axios.post('/some-route').then((res) => {
    router.push({ path: '/register ' }) // <-- Redirect the current page to /redirect
  })
}

</script>
```

> You need to have registered the route `/register` in your `routes.js` file.

Reference: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html